# Symfony 5 UniqueEntity Form Validation Constraints

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm using Symfony Forms to create and validate my form I'm not using Assert in Entity I'm using constraints in Forms. while using UniqueEntity having an issue can't associate the Entity or Repository to the constraints.

**My FormType**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Business;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

class BusinessNameFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('business_title', TextType::class, [
                "label" => "Business Title",
                "help"  => "This will be the name of your workspace.",
                "constraints" => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['min' => 3]),
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => '/^[a-z0-9]+$/',
                        'match'   => True,
                        'message' => 'Only a-z, 0-9 values are allowed.'
                    ]),
                    new UniqueEntity([
                        'entityClass' => Business::class,
                        'fields' => 'title'
                    ]),
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```php
<?php


namespace App\Controller;


use App\Form\BusinessNameFormType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/register", name="register_")
 * Class RegisterBusinessController
 */
class RegisterBusinessController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/step-one", name="step_one")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function stepOne(Request $request): Response
    {

        $businessNameForm = $this->createForm(BusinessNameFormType::class);
        $businessNameForm->handleRequest($request);
        if($businessNameForm->isSubmitted() && $businessNameForm->isValid()){
            dd($businessNameForm->getData());
        }

        return $this->render("security/register_business/step_one.html.twig", [
           'businessNameForm' => $businessNameForm->createView()
        ]);

    }
}
```

After that having an error while validating having an error.
[image]

Comment: You have a TextType in your form and the constraint expects an entity, so would probably work better with an EntityType. You could try using a DataTransformer or form events to get an entity object instead or you could write a custom constraint that uses Doctrine to check if a business with that title already exists instead

Answer (score 1):

UniqueEntity has to be applied against the entity (not to the field). But you  can use it in setDefaults:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'constraints' => [
            new UniqueEntity([
                'entityClass' => Business::class,
                'fields' => 'title',
            ]),
        ],
```

Also, it seems your form field should be named as 'title' instead of 'business_title'.